# Entropy of the bivariate Gaussian copula: Closed-form analytical solution

Tags: logarithms, information-theory, entropy, gaussian, copula

### Background

The *bivariate* Gaussian **copula function** is

$$C_{\rho}(u,v)=∫_{-∞}^{Φ^{-1}(u)}∫_{-∞}^{Φ^{-1}(v)}\frac{1}{2π\sqrt{1-ρ^2}}×exp⁡(-\frac{x^2+y^2-2ρxy}{2(1-ρ^2)})dxdy.$$

The *multivariate* Gaussian **copula density** (being the second mixed partial derivative of the copula function) is derived as follows:

Let $x=[\Phi^{-1}(u_1),\ldots,\Phi^{-1}(u_n)]^{\top}$. Then
\begin{align}
c(u_1,\ldots,u_n;\Sigma)&=\frac{\partial^nC(u_1,.\ldots,u_n;\Sigma)}{\partial u_1\cdots\partial u_n}=\frac{\Phi(x;0,\Sigma)}{\prod_{i=1}^n \phi(x_i)} \\
&=(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}x\right)\times\prod_{i=1}^n (2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(\frac{1}{2}x_i^2\right) \\
&=|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}x+\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}x\right) \\
&=|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\!\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}(\Sigma^{-1}-I)x\right).
\end{align}

This reduces nicely in the bivariate case, $n=2$, as
$$
c\left(u_{1}, u_{2} ; \rho\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}} \exp \left\{-\frac{\rho^{2}\left(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}\right)-2 \rho x_{1} x_{2}}{2\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)}\right\}
$$

### Question

How can we derive the **entropy of the bivariate Gaussian copula density** as a closed-form analytical solution? Here is my attempt based on helpful comments below:
\begin{align}
h(c(u,v)) &= \int c(u,v) \ln c(u,v) \mathrm{d} x_1 \mathrm{d} x_2\\
&= \mathbb{E}[ -\log c(u,v)] \\ 
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ -\log \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}} \exp \left\{-
\frac{\rho^{2}\left(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}\right)-2 \rho x_{1} x_{2}}{2\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)}\right\}\right]  \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\log (1-\rho^2) + \frac{\rho^2( X_1^2 + X_2^2) - 2\rho X_1X_2}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right]\\
&=  \frac{1}{2}\log (1-\rho^2) + \frac{\rho^2 \mathbb{E}( X_1^2 + X_2^2) - 2\rho \mathbb{E}(X_1 X_2)}{2(1-\rho^2)} \\
&=  \frac{1}{2}\log (1-\rho^2) + \frac{\rho^2 \mathbb{E}( X_1^2) + \rho^2 
 \mathbb{E}( X_2^2) - 2\rho \mathbb{E}(X_1)\mathbb{E}(X_2)}{2(1-\rho^2)} \\
&=  \log (1-\rho^2) + \frac{1}{(1-\rho^2)} \left[ \rho^2 \mathbb{E}( X_1^2) + \rho^2 
 \mathbb{E}( X_2^2) - 2\rho \mathbb{E}(X_1)\mathbb{E}(X_2) \right]\\
&= ?
\end{align}

Comment: Suggestion - instead of expanding everything out, write $$H(c) = \mathbb{E}[ -\log c(X_1, X_2)] \\ = \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\log (1-\rho^2) + \frac{\rho^2( X_1^2 + X_2^2) - 2\rho X_1X_2}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right].$$ To finish the calculation, all you need to supply are the values of $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2], \mathbb{E}[X_2^2]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]$.

Comment: thanks, I've edited with my attempt using your approach. how does it look