# Integrate $\int_{0}^{1} u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha}(1-\alpha) \log \left((1-\alpha) u^{-\alpha}\right) d u $

Tags: integration, statistics, logarithms, entropy, copula

Where $c(u, v)=u^{-\alpha}(1-\alpha) $ is the Marshall-Olkin copula density, we have the following integral:
\begin{align}
I_{1} &=\iint_{E} c(u, v) \log c(u, v) d u d v \\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}} u^{-\alpha}(1-\alpha) \log \left(u^{-\alpha}(1-\alpha)\right) d v d u
\end{align}

They calculate this integral as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{1} &=\int_{0}^{1} u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha}(1-\alpha) \log \left((1-\alpha) u^{-\alpha}\right) d u \\
&=(1-\alpha) \log (1-\alpha) \int_{0}^{1} u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha} d u-\alpha(1-\alpha) \int_{0}^{1} u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha} \log u d u \\
&=\frac{(1-\alpha) \beta \log (1-\alpha)}{\alpha-\alpha \beta+\alpha}+\frac{\alpha(1-\alpha) \beta^{2}}{(\alpha-\alpha \beta+\beta)^{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$
In the last 3 lines, what are all the steps in-between? I don't understand how the first becomes the second, and the second becomes the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equality follows from standard properties of the logarithm, explicitly:
$$\log{((1-\alpha)u^{-\alpha})}=\log{(1-\alpha)}+\log{(u^{-\alpha})} = \log{(1-\alpha)}-\alpha\log{(u)}$$
The second follow by the standard integral of $x^{a}$ and integration by parts, explicitly:
$$\int_{0}^{1} u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha} du=\left[\frac{u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha+1}}{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha+1}\right]_{0}^{1}=\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\alpha \beta+\beta}$$ (I think the $+\alpha$ should be a $+\beta$ in the denominator)
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha} \log u du &=\left[\frac{u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha+1}\log u}{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha+1}\right]_0^1-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha}}{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha+1}du\\
&=-\left[\frac{u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha+1}}{(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\alpha+1)^2}\right]^1_0\\
&=-\frac{\beta^2}{(\alpha-\alpha \beta+\beta)^2}
\end{align}
Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, maybe you can also solve this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917813/entropy-of-the-gaussian-copula-closed-form-analytical-solution

Comment: I can take a look! As I'm new here and looking to build up reputation, if you're happy with this answer please could you accept it? Thanks :)

Comment: I was still looking over it since it's alot, but oh well there it is in advance. first question is: regarding $\log{(1-\alpha)}-\alpha\log{(u)}$, why did $\log{(1-\alpha)}$ instantly come outside of the integral altogether, whereas $\log{(u)}$ remained inside the integral? Both of them are logarithms that started out *inside* the integral, but only one made its way out on the second line

Comment: We're integrating over $u$ so we can't take any terms involving $u$ out of the integral, but as $\log(1-\alpha)$ is a constant we can take it out of the integral freely.